# Get Javascript div to slide out on appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

Got a bit of basic JS here that I want to slide out rather than just appear (looks glitchy)

I've tried a few things but just cant manage it, any ideas? heres the code followed by the Jsfiddle:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style>
body{margin:0;}
#foo{min-width:400px; height:100%; background-color:#9C0; display:none; position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;}


</style>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo" >



</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRWHw/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've update your fiddle, using VanillaJS [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/wRWHw/3/) it works perfectly well

```
document.getElementById('bar').onclick = (function()
{
    var that, interval, step = 20,
    id = document.getElementById('foo'),
    handler = function()
    {
        that = that || this;
        that.onclick = null;
        id = document.getElementById('foo');
        interval =setInterval (function()
        {
            id.style.right = (parseInt(id.style.right, 10) + step)+ 'px';
            if (id.style.right === '0px' || id.style.right === '-400px')
            {
                that.onclick = handler;
                clearInterval(interval);
                if (id.style.right === '-400px')
                {
                    id.style.display = 'none';
                }
                step *= -1;
            }
            else
            {
                id.style.display = 'block';
            }
        },100);
    };
    return handler;
}());
```

The code explained:

- Attach the click handler in JS, because we're going to have to unbind/bind it dynamically
- instead of assigning a handler directly, I'm using a closure (for the interval and DOM references)
- `handler` is the actual event handler, which assigns its context (the clicked element) to `that`, so we can reference it in the interval callback and *unbinds* the handler.
- The interval changes the position of the element by `step` pixels (set this value to whatever you like).
- If the div is at position 0 or -400, cancel the interval (that's why we need the closure, to keep the interval ID in scope, but not expose it globally), and re-bind the click handler, `step *= -1`, to invert the animation
- Set the display property

This interval sequence is set to occur every 100ms, which is a bit shaky, lower the value of `set` to 10, and set the interval at `50` should smoothen things out

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: done submitted too soon, sorry for that

Comment: kudos + (+1) for explaination.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly then, use jQuery for sliding effects.

[JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wRWHw/1/)

**JS:**

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
    $("#foo").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: pulling in jquery for a animation insted of explaning how animation works.

Comment: Wait, I am giving your solutionthrough a fiddle :)

Comment: From the JS tag description _"If a library or framework is used, then tag the question with the appropriate tags [...] However, if a framework is not used or necessary, do not include these tags"_. No JQ tag, no JQ answers please

Comment: sound fair to me. Mohammed we do not need to Jquery all the time. In plain words it increases the load on the server.

Comment: But I was just giving a little solution :'( my bad

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: I didn't down-vote, I merely wanted to point out the fact that this answer, though technically valid, does not respect the tags the way they should be respected. They're meant to organize questions and answers alike. Often, if I want a straight JS answer, I end up sifting through tons of jQ snippets, before getting to what it is I'm after. That's all

Answer (score -1):

I've updated your fiddle for use of jQuery; http://jsfiddle.net/wRWHw/2/

```
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
        $("#" + id).slideToggle("slow");
    }
```

Comment: Check JS tag description: _"If a library or framework is used, then tag the question with the appropriate tags [...] However, if a framework is not used or necessary, do not include these tags"_ Don't assume jQ, especially if OP didn't set up a jQ fiddle